# zend framework 2 simple integration

Tags: zend-framework2

I am planning to build a project using zend framework 2.
But i find it very hard to setup zf2.
It is not easy to setup the framework and start working.

What i am looking is copy required zf2 files, put into the project and start working.

Like in cakephp where you need to make changes in database configurations and start working.

Can anybody help for this issue. this will be useful for many other developers also.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [SkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/)? It provides everything you need: Pre-setup bootstrapping, the directory structure, a basic application configuration.

Just clone it into your web directory and make sure that `vendor/ZF2` gets cloned as well (`--recursive` flag).

This is currently the easiest approach to get started with a new ZF2 project.

If you need further assistance, please state your question more specificly.

// Edit: Although it makes sense to use composer or at least git to pull everything directly, you can just download the project (SekeletonApplication and ZF2) from Git. In my opinion, you shouldn't be too lazy here. Using composer etc. will save you a lot of time that you can spend on implementation.

Comment: I am thankful to you Daniel but what i am looking for is simple integration like cakephp do. Copy required files, make changes in db files and start working.

Comment: I have made some changes in my question also, i have set up **SkeletonAppliction** also but i need simple integration.

Comment: To be honest, you're contradictory here. You want something you call simple integration but you don't want to use helpful tools to achieve this. ZF2 DOES require some work to set it up, you can't make a working empty ZF2 "installation" magically appear from nothing. You asked 19 hrs ago and you've obviously still no solution that's satisfying to you. So why don't you just take an hour (maximum), check composer and open a command shell? Believe us, this will pay off.

Comment: It is not 19 hours As i have already said that i have set **SkeletonAppliction** using composer and it is working perfectly. I am using zf1 from last 2 years and it's working looks simple than zf2 to me. I am feeling a little odd probably because of the first time use of zf2. As of now i accept you to use the documents provided by zend to setup application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting up ZF2 without the use of the command line is MUCH more of a pita than using it. Sure, you can download the SkeletonApplication and then you can Download ZF2 Core Library and put it into your include_path, but that's not too great.

I really suggest learning about the command line. I'm a windows user myself and hated it at first, but after getting around the first problems, i - now - find it really handy.

If you have trouble setting up your stuff or understanding it all, you may find my tutorial helpful which you can find right here: [Zend Framework 2 Installation on Xampp for Windows](http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/)

Comment: Sam thanks for your response but what i am looking for is simple integration like cakephp do. Copy required files, make changes in db files and start working.

Comment: There is no such thing like this. And by what the framework wants to achieve, PERSONALLY i call this a good thing. Even i do see your point for wanting such (i was just like that ;) ). The minimum thing is to download the SkeletonApplication and then the framework by hand. That's a two step thing - less is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I found the Skeleton application easy and quick to install, but I didn't need the translations that are included. As a result I created a stripped down, bare bones version which you are welcome to use.

You will find the [ZendMinimumApplication](https://github.com/vascowhite/ZendMinimumApplication) on github.